# Llamar a otra funcion/componente usando useState de React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

Soy novato utilizando hooks, pero lo que quiero hacer es al darle click en el botón de la función Home, que desplegue el contenido de Contact o Contacto que sería simplemente Youre in Contact y Have a good day !!! Este es mi código de ejemplo, espero que sea de ayuda.

```
Import React, { useState } from ‘react’;

function Contact() {
    return(
        <h2>Yore in Contact</h2>
        <p>Have a good day !!!</p>
    );
}




function Home() {
    const contact = useState(new Contact())
    return(
        <h2>Youre in Home</h2>
                  <button onClick={contact}>Goto Contact</button>
    );
}
```

Comment: En React, no es necesario crear la instacia del componente con new, React hace eso internamente, solo tienes que llamarlo como <Contact />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con esto, hay errores en tus hooks, ya que no puedes renderizar dos elementos sin que tengan un padre, puedes meter los elementos dentro de un div, o en este caso dentro de un Fragment "<> Elementos... < />"

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Contact() {
    return(
        <>
          <h2>Yore in Contact</h2>
          <p>Have a good day !!!</p>
        </>
    );
}

function Home() {
    const [contact,setContact] = useState(null);

    return(
        <>
          <h2>Youre in Home</h2>
          <button 
            onClick={
              () => setContact(contact === null ? <Contact /> : null)}
          >
            Goto Contact
          </button>
          {contact}
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opcion a la respuesta de @Brandon seria esta:

```
function Home() {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState(false);
  return(
      <>
        <h2>Youre in Home</h2>
        <button 
          onClick={() => setContact(true)}
        >
          Goto Contact
        </button>
        {contact && <Contact />}
      </>
  );
}
```

En este ejemplo, el state `contact` seria una bandera que si es verdadera muestra el componente `<Contact />`.